# Long Date Time Convert to Date Time C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert long datetime to a simple datetime in c#.. I tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked.. The format of long datetime is like this "Sunday, January 21, 2011 12:03:00" and I need to convert it to this "1/21/2011 12:03:00" . This is my code.

```
string chk = null;
                    string[] splt = l.Message.Split('#');
                    for (int i = 0; i < splt.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string[] parts = splt[i].Split(':');
                        char prefix = Convert.ToChar(parts[0]);
                        string value = parts[1];

                        switch (prefix)
                        {
                            case 'T':
                                l.truck = value;
                                break;
                            case 'D':
                                l.driver = value;
                                break;
                            case 'R':
                                l.receivedby = value;
                                break;
                            case 'A':
                                l.arriveddate = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(value)).ToLongDateString();
                                var arrvd = DateTime.Parse(l.arriveddate, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                                l.arriveddate = arrvd.ToString();
                                break;
                            case 'U':
                                l.unloaddate = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(value)).ToLongDateString();
                                var unlod = DateTime.Parse(l.unloaddate, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                                l.unloaddate = unlod.ToString();
                                break;
                            case 'N':
                                l.deliverynote = value;
                                break;
                            case 'L':
                                l.deliverdate = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(value)).ToLongDateString();
                                var dlvrd = DateTime.Parse(l.deliverdate, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                                l.deliverynote = dlvrd.ToString();
                                break;
                            case 'S':
                                l.deliverystatus = value;
                                break;
                            case 'M':
                                l.mac = value;
                                break;
                            case 'C':
                                l.msgcreatedate = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(value)).ToLongDateString();
                                var msgcrtd = DateTime.Parse(l.msgcreatedate, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                                l.msgcreatedate = msgcrtd.ToString();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really start to use the built-in DateTime type:

```
string input = "Friday, January 21, 2011 12:03:00";

// read input of a given format
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// create a string representing the DateTime in another format
string output = dt.ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// output is now "1/21/2011 12:03:00", regardless the culture
```

Depending on the culture you're using, it may be enough for you to just use `string output = dt.ToString();`, e.g. when using `en-GB`.

BTW: January the 21rst was a Friday in 2011.

Comment: I actually haven't thought of it - but how does `ParseExact` behave when passing in `Sunday` for something that is a `Friday`?

Comment: `FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, it should work

```
string date = myDate.ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is all datetime formats